# Find roots using scipy.optimize.fsolve. What went wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize
```

Basic variables:

```
eee=0.289;
nn=0.63;
E1k=0.0935;
pp=1.25;
B1k=0.12;
v1k=0.126;
Bkk=3.14;
VKb=0.76;
rKb=1.754;
```

Motion model, these equations are numerically integrated over:

```
def D2(y,t):
    Vr,Vn,r,v,Q,dQ_dt=y
    dVr_dt=(aob2*np.sin(Q))/(1-(aob2*t/wb))-1/(r**2)+(Vn**2)/r
    dVn_dt=(aob2*np.cos(Q))/(1-((aob2*t)/wb))-(Vr*Vn)/r
    dr_dt=Vr
    dB_dt=Vn/r
    Qt=0
    dQ_dtt=0
    return [dVr_dt,dVn_dt,dr_dt,dB_dt,Qt,dQ_dtt]
```

Function, the roots of which we seek:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
def VrVnRB(x):
    v2oA=2*np.arctan(np.sqrt((1+eee)/(1-eee))*np.tan(x[0]/2))
    if v2oA>v1k:
    v2o=v2oA
    else:
    v2o=v2oA+2*np.pi
    t2=np.linspace(0,x[3],500)
    tpas=1/nn*(x[0]-E1k+eee*(np.sin(E1k)-np.sin(x[0])))
    Vro2=eee*np.sin(v2o)/np.sqrt(pp)
    Vno2=(1+eee*np.cos(v2o))/np.sqrt(pp)
    ro2=pp/(1+eee*np.cos(v2o))
    Bo2=B1k+v2o-v1k
    yo2=[Vro2,Vno2,ro2,Bo2,x[1],x[2]]
    EE2=odeint(D2,yo2,t2)
    Vrk=EE2[:,0]
    Vrk=Vrk[-1]
    Vnk=EE2[:,1]
    Vnk=Vnk[-1]
    rk =EE2[:,2]
    rk= rk[-1]
    Bk =EE2[:,3]
    Bk= Bk[-1]
    return [Vrk,Vnk-VKb,rk-rKb,Bk-Bkk]
x0=[E20,Qo2,dQ_dt2,t2b]
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
t1k=scipy.optimize.fsolve(VrVnRB,x0)
```

But interpreter resents:

```
File "<tmp 2>", line 36, in <module>
    t1k=scipy.optimize.fsolve(VrVnRB,x0)
  File "C:\pyzo2013c\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 139, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
  File "C:\pyzo2013c\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 208, in _root_hybr
    ml, mu, epsfcn, factor, diag)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

I do not understand what my mistake. Please, help.

Comment: To `fsolve` to work you need to have as many independent variables as equations. While yes, you do pass in 4 values and ask for 4 values, that is not the same as 4 equations and 4 unknowns. You need to make sure that changing the value of say `t2b` can be done independent of any change done in the other three. Even then, it doesn't seem like you could, or maybe should, count that as one of your unknowns. Lastly, it seems like you are doing parameter estimation and, if so, should probably formulate this as a least-squares problem.